# Load PFFile Into UIImageView in Swift 2.1/Xcode 7.2

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, swift2

I'm really having a hard time trying to get the image to load from Parse... I have it all set up that it sends the image as a file through JavaScript to Parse (see screenshot) and now I'm trying to load the image into my UIImageView in Swift 2.1/Xcode 7.2 Beta. No errors return and the rest of the app functions like it's supposed to. I cannot seem to get it working, though. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
    if currentUser != nil {

        if let companyImage = currentUser!["pic"] as? PFFile {
            companyImage.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ ( imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if error == nil{
                    self.pic.image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                } else {
                    print("No image found")
                }
            })
        }
```

[Here's a screenshot of what shows up in Parse after I save it through a website I created with JavaScript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knRHb.png)

**Edit:**

I have also edited the Info.plist file in my app to make sure that requests made to the internet could be handled, and it worked because I was able to load the user's username.

Comment: Fill in the rest of the rows with files. You could be getting an error making it not return anything because the other two rows are empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't think the current user contains other object than the default.To be sure make sure you have the user data of the row.
so try this

```
var query = PFUser.query()
query.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser().objectId)
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
  (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

  if error == nil {
    // The find succeeded.
    print("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) scores.")
    // Do something with the found objects
    if let objects = objects {
if let companyImage = objects[0]!["pic"] as? PFFile {
            companyImage.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ ( imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if error == nil{
                    self.pic.image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                } else {
                    print("No image found")
                }
            })

    }
  } else {
    // Log details of the failure
    print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")
  }
}
```

Comment: You're a miracle worker.... Thanks so much! :) Just a side question, you don't have to answer it if you don't know, but if I were trying to retrieve an image from a post, how would I go about doing that? Thanks again!

Comment: I would like to help you if you could give more info.From which post?

Comment: Right, I'm sorry for being too vague... I do that a lot. xD             I've made a script that goes through one of my classes in Parse named "Posts". When it's done with this, it prints that there are 3 posts (there are). How would I be able to get the information of something inside a post, like "post[0].title"? I've tried several variations, but nothing is working... The method is similar to the one you used above, if you want to use that for a reference...

Comment: if let posts = objects as? [PFobject]{for post in posts{var title = post["title"]} }

Comment: Thanks for replying, but it's still not working... Here's the code I used: 'if let posts = objects as? [PFObject]{
                        for post in posts{
                            let title = post["title"]
                        print(title!)
                        }
                    }'

Comment: Output says: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: 1-print the post to see if there are really retrieved fro parse.2-check if the field name is right.3-Spent some time reading parse document it may be very useful in time

Comment: Ok, thanks... I've done all three of those, especially #3, but I can't figure it out. Oh well, thanks for your help anyway, it's much appreciated! ;)

Comment: Actually, it was all my bad. Turns out I had it figured out anyway, there were just some glitches with other parts of the storyboard that were making it error there for some reason.... Sorry to bug you. Thanks a lot! :3